# Mathematical equation for 'Relative and absolute power' of a signal

Tags: continuous-signals

Can somebody provide me with the mathematical equation to calculate relative and absolute power of a signal (continuous) from FFT.

Comment: No idea what you mean by "relative" power. Can you supply a definition of the term and or cite a source that uses that wording

Comment: Absolute power corrupts absolutely and can be calculated as $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x(t)|^2\,\mathrm dt \qquad \text{or} \qquad \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty |x[n]|^2.$$